# awk syntax error "invalid character in expression"

Tags: awk

I have a script like below

```
#!/bin/ksh
while read -r line
do
        cname=$(echo ${line} | awk -F"[ ]" '{print $10}')
        scode=$(echo ${line} | awk -F"[ ]" '{print $(NF-1)}')
        [[ ( ${scode} -ge 200 ) && ( ${scode} -le 399 ) ]] && {
                echo ${line} >> ${cname}_access.log
                }
        [[ ( ${scode} -ge 400 ) && ( ${scode} -le 599 ) ]] && {
                echo ${line} >> ${cname}_error.log
                }
done < /home/vizion/Desktop/adn_DF9D_20140515_0001.log
```

I am getting `Error "line 6: :: invalid character in expression - +http://www.google.com/bot.html)""`

My log below

```
66.249.75.49 - - [15/May/2014:00:12:01 +0000] "GET abc.def.com/80DF9D/plantronics/us/support/software-downloads/download.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 3956 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" "-"
```

Please correct me where I am wrong

Comment: what parts of this log you need to extract? Do you want `200` after `HTTP/1.1` to be `scode` and `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)` to be `cname`?

Comment: Needs to be extract abc.def.com and scode

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you want. I have used this:

```
awk '{scode=$9;cname=substr($7,1,index($7,"/")-1);
      if(scode >= 200 && scode < 399){print >> cname"_access.log"}
      else{if(scode >= 400 && scode < 599){print >> cname"_error.log"}}}' logfile
```

logfile:

```
66.249.75.49 - - [15/May/2014:00:12:01 +0000] "GET abc.def.com/80DF9D/plantronics/us/support/software-downloads/download.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 3956 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" "-"
```

It created a file named `abc.def.com_access.log`. The content of the file was:

```
66.249.75.49 - - [15/May/2014:00:12:01 +0000] "GET abc.def.com/80DF9D/plantronics/us/support/software-downloads/download.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 3956 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" "-"
```

Comment: Hey thanks but when generating access.log and error.log name not coming with "cname". it is coming like _access log and _error log

Comment: @user3319390, does your log is exactly like the one you have posted? or did you tried the code with the log you have posted?

Comment: it's same with production just change to website name.

Comment: @user3319390, does `awk '{print $7}' logfile` prints the website name? and does you have `/` before website name? for example `http://`?

Comment: I was just get the split command using like "awk '{split($7,c,"/"); print c[3]}' " i am getting the name of the site still i am not able to push the logs respective file like error or access

Comment: @user3319390, does `awk '{split($7,c,"/"); cname=c[3]; print cname"_access.log";}'` prints the file name you need? i.e `abc.def.com_access.log`?

Comment: Now i am getting exact result using below code    #!/bin/ksh
while read -r line
do
        cname=$(echo ${line} | awk '{split($7,c,"/"); print c[3]}')
        scode=$(echo ${line} | awk -F"[ ]" '{print $9}')
        [[ ( ${scode} -ge 200 ) && ( ${scode} -le 399 ) ]] && {
                echo ${line} >> ${cname}_access.log
                }
        [[ ( ${scode} -ge 400 ) && ( ${scode} -le 599 ) ]] && {
                echo ${line} >> ${cname}_error.log
                }
done < /home/vizion/Desktop/adn_DF9D_20140515_0001.log

Answer (score 0):

Using below script

```
#!/bin/ksh
while read -r line
do
        cname=$(echo ${line} | awk '{split($7,c,"/"); print c[3]}')
        scode=$(echo ${line} | awk -F"[ ]" '{print $9}')
        [[ ( ${scode} -ge 200 ) && ( ${scode} -le 399 ) ]] && {
                echo ${line} >> ${cname}_access.log
                }
        [[ ( ${scode} -ge 400 ) && ( ${scode} -le 599 ) ]] && {
                echo ${line} >> ${cname}_error.log
                }
done < /home/vizion/Desktop/adn_DF9D_20140515_0001.log
```